# how to get value of two dimension of array when using for loop in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Below is my code, my question is how to get value in the body of for loop?

```
#!/bin/bash

ar1=("moneyclub8.com" "fwdv4u")
ar2=("ghist2811.com" "n9dv03")
ar3=("ghost.com" "eccsml") 
arr=(ar1 ar2 ar3);

for data in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    reallist=$data[@]

    domain= ""  ##<== how to get value here ?
    code= "" ##<== how to get value here ?

    for key in "${!reallist}" ; do
        echo "the key is: $key"
    done
done
```

Comment: please update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) exepcted output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea for the dynamic array reference is to use a `nameref` (`declare -n`):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ar1=("moneyclub8.com" "fwdv4u")
ar2=("ghist2811.com" "n9dv03")
ar3=("ghost.com" "eccsml")
arr=(ar1 ar2 ar3);

for data in "${arr[@]}" ; do
    declare -n reallist=$data               # use nameref to access underlying array

    domain="${reallist[0]}"                 # see output from "typeset -p ar1 ar2 ar3"
    code="${reallist[1]}"                   # to validate these references

    typeset -p domain code                  # display content of variables

    for key in "${!reallist[@]}" ; do       # added "[@]" to provide access to array indices
        echo "the key is: $key"
    done
done
```

Running this script generates:

```
declare -- domain="moneyclub8.com"
declare -- code="fwdv4u"
the key is: 0
the key is: 1
declare -- domain="ghist2811.com"
declare -- code="n9dv03"
the key is: 0
the key is: 1
declare -- domain="ghost.com"
declare -- code="eccsml"
the key is: 0
the key is: 1
```